# Pysnmp can't resolve OID's from snmp trap

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib

I'm trying to resolve the OIDs that are received on an SNMP Trap from an HP switch stack but they only resolve down to a certain level and stop. It's like the HP MIBs are not being loaded. It's unclear from all the documentation I can find on pysnmp if this is the appropriate way to add custom MIBs and resolve OIDs from a trap.
MIBs can be downloaded [here](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/Downloads/DownloadSoftware.aspx?SoftwareReleaseUId=23278&ProductNumber=J9028A&lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=3231819&SaidNumber=).

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import view, builder, rfc1902
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv, mibvar

# Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
# to socket transport dispatcher
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()
build = snmpEngine.getMibBuilder()
build.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource("C:/Users/t/Documents/mibs"))
viewer = view.MibViewController(build)

# Transport setup

# UDP over IPv4, first listening interface/port
config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName + (1,),
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 162))
)

# SNMPv1/2c setup

# SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, '????', 'public')


# Callback function for receiving notifications
# noinspection PyUnusedLocal,PyUnusedLocal,PyUnusedLocal
def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName, varBinds, cbCtx):
    print('Notification from ContextEngineId "%s", ContextName "%s"' % (contextEngineId.prettyPrint(),
                                                                        contextName.prettyPrint()))
    for name, val in varBinds:
        print(name)
        symbol = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(name).resolveWithMib(viewer).getMibSymbol()
        print(symbol[1])



# Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)

snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)  # this job would never finish

# Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send confirmations
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

Output upon receiving a trap:

```
Notification from ContextEngineId "0x80004fb8056ed891e8", ContextName ""
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
sysUpTime
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
snmpTrapOID
1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0
snmpTrapAddress
1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.4.0
snmpTrapCommunity
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0
snmpTrapEnterprise
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.9
enterprises
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.0.1
enterprises
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.0.2
enterprises
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.0.3
enterprises
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.0.4
enterprises
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.29.1.0.5
enterprises
```

As you can see many distinct OIDs just resolve to "enterprises". I am using pysnmp 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems that only the core MIBs are loaded.

If you want to follow this quite low-level path, then you need to pre-compile all your ASN.1 MIBs (those you pulled from HPE site) with the [mibdump](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html) tool into pysnmp format. Then put those *.py files into some directory and point pysnmp to it through `build.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource())` call.

Also, make sure to pre-load up all those MIBs at once on startup by invoking `build.loadModules()` (w/o arguments).

Comment: Is there a less low-level path? I couldn't seem to see one.